# javascript php internal server error 500 random

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Apologies if this question is a bit vague, but I have no idea how to make it more specific. I am a beginner when it comes to javascript. I have a web page which sends a number of ajax calls to the server to call php scripts which runs some sql against a mysql database. Everything was working fine then all of a sudden I started to get an internal server error 500 on one of my ajax calls. The ajax call is placed in a function, it works most of the time. Only when I pass the function one specific sql query does it give the error. I've tested the query in my database manually and it works so its not an issue with the query that I am passing. The strange thing is, since the error has started, every now and then it does work, however most of the time it is not working, the error seems to be somewhat random. I realise that with limited information it may be impossible to give an exact answer, but has anyone experienced anything like this before? OR does anyone have any clues as to how I can get to the bottom of this. I've tried everything. I will paste the function that is causing the error (not sure if that will help at all). The error comes on the "xmlhttp.send();" line.

```
function phpRequest2(prov, phpsc, funct, bolL) {

  <!-- document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = qry; -->

  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = prov;

  xmlhttp.open("GET", phpsc + ".php?qry=" + prov, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var arrLocs = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      funct(arrLocs, bolL);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: The 500 error is not on the AJAX call itself, it is on the PHP - likely because it receives something it isn't expecting from the AJAX call. The web server's error logs will reveal more about what the actual problem is.

Comment: 500 means there was a server-side error.  Check your PHP logs, web server logs, turn on PHP error reporting, debug your server-side code, etc.  Basically you need to find the "real" error message, 500 is just the server's way of telling the browser that something went wrong.

Comment: Please could you guide me as to how best to debug my server side code or turn on PHP error reporting. Sorry for the basic question, as I said I'm a beginner....

Comment: Google it, dude: "php debug"

Comment: What's in the prov parameter? I think that's probably what's causing the problem

Comment: Hi All. I'm not having much luck debugging. My problem seems to be coming when I call a php script, then very soon after, call the same script (just passing it a different sql query to run). Is it possible that the second php call is being passed to the server before the server has finished processing the  first php call? If so, is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You best bet at finding out the reason when you get the Error 500 is to edit your php.ini file and change the following parameters

```
display_errors = Off 
display_startup_errors = Off
```

to

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

Hopefully that should give you exact details on what your error is and thereby help you solve it.